# How can I create cascade property based on number of interactions in a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, function, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
  var dataCategories = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = 3; i < len; i++) {
       dataCategories.push({name: i, categories: [] })
    }
   console.log(dataCategories) 
  /* Result:
   [{name: 0, categories: [] }, {name: 1, categories: [] }, {name: 2, categories: [] }]
  */
```

but I need a result like the following

```
 [{name: 0, 
  categories: [{
        name: 1, 
        categories: [{
            name: 2, 
            categories: [] 
        }]
   }] 
 }]
```

how can i get that cascading result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `reduceRight` instead, iterating over an array of 0 to 2:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
const output = arr.reduceRight(
  (categories, name) => [{ name, categories }],
  []
);
console.log(output);
```

Or, for an arbitrary number:

```js
const length = 3;
const arr = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i);
const output = arr.reduceRight(
  (categories, name) => [{ name, categories }],
  []
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: How can I make the "name" property take the value of the "val" property of the array?
var arr = [{val: 0}, {val: 1}, {val: 2}];
var output = arr.reduceRight(
      function(categories, name) { 
       console.log(categories, name[]);
       return  [{ name, categories }]
    },
  []
);
console.log(output);

Comment: Map the array to just the vals first? `arr.map(({ val }) => val)`